# R Find the intersection of two lines for each group

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, predictive-models

Given the following data.frame:

```
testdat <- structure(list(id = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
15, 15, 15), x = c(0, 10, 24, 38, 0, 10, 24, 38, 0, 10, 24, 38, 
0, 10, 38), y = c(70.7, 78, 79.8, 81.4, 85, 90.2, 91, 93.4, 74, 
77.1, 81, 84.1, 62.2, 66, 68.8), threshold = c(80.3, 80.3, 80.3, 
80.3, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 82.6, 82.6, 82.6, 82.6, 67.1, 67.1, 
67.1)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to find the points where each sample (*id*) crosses a specific values (*threshold*).

The plotted data looks like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data=testdat, aes(x=x, y=y, group=id)) + 
  # raw data
  geom_point( aes(y=y, alpha=0.3)) + 
  geom_line(  color="green", alpha = 0.9)+
  # lm
  geom_smooth(method='lm', alpha=0.5, se=FALSE) +
  # Threshold
  geom_hline( aes(yintercept = threshold, group=id), color='red', alpha=.5) + theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~id, nrow=4)
p
```

[image: line plot]

On this plot:

- Red line == threshold
- Green line == raw data
- Blue line == linear regression

For each *id*, I would like to know at which *x* the red crosses the green and the blue one.

A dplyr solution, adding two new columns to the initial data.frame would be nice but after hours of mucking around with this problem, I'm going anywhere...

This seems trivial but I couldn't any example of similar problem.

Comment: The lines, by default, are least square fits of the form $y = \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1  x.$ Algebra tells us such a line crosses a threshold $t$ where $t = y,$ yielding $x = (t - \hat\beta_0)/\hat\beta_1$ provided $\beta_1\ne 0.$  It's up to you to compute those lines (use `lm` for example), extract its coefficients (use `coefficients`), and compute this solution.  Please avoid the subtle error of regressing $x$ against $y$ and just plugging in $t:$ unless the data are already perfectly correlated, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: It's easy to find where the regression line crosses the threshold (as described by @whuber). It's harder to find where the green segments cross the threshold, if at all. Note that in your example data the red line and the green segments cross at exactly one point. But in general there might be more than one crossing (inside the observed range of x values). It's even possible that a green segment is parallel to the red line.